# How can I pass an id of element to url when I scroll to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, frontend

I have a set of elements on a page that have ids in them.

The client wants to be able to have a scroll that attaches the id to the end of the url each time you scroll to it.

So heres the markup:

HTML:

```
<section class="body-large scrolled" id="drop-in-membership">

</section>      

      <section class="body-large scrolled" id="hotdesk-membership">

</section>      

      <section class="body-large scrolled" id="resident-membership">

</section>      

      <section class="body-large scrolled" id="studios">

</section>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

                var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
                var $scrolledDivs = $('.scrolled');

                $.each($scrolledDivs, function(item) {
                    if( $(item).offset().top == winTop ) {

                    //console.log( this.attr('id') );
                    window.location.href + scrolledDivs.attr('id');
                }

                });
            });
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You don't change the location. Try ```window.location.href += '/#' + scrolledDivs.attr('id')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the kind of thing you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfd7w/

```
function CheckScroll(el) {
    var top_of_object = el.offset().top;
    var bottom_of_window = $('.window').height();
    if (bottom_of_window >= top_of_object) {
        $('#result').text('ID ("'+el.attr('id')+'") is now showing');
    }    
}

$('.window').scroll(function(){
    $('section').each(function() {
        CheckScroll($(this));        
    });
});
```

EDIT:

For window scrolling:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfd7w/3/

```
function CheckScroll(el) {
    var top_of_object = el.offset().top;
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (bottom_of_window >= top_of_object) {
        $('#result').text('ID ("'+el.attr('id')+'") is now showing');
    }    
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('section').each(function() {
        CheckScroll($(this));        
    });
});
```

Comment: hmmm, that does not work when scrolling the body or window?? This is where I have been encountering errors.

Comment: Here's it working for $(window) - http://jsfiddle.net/bfd7w/2/. It needed `var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();`

Comment: thats great, is there a way that with this I can toggle the ids onto the end of the url? Everytime I do it it just appends them onto the url and keeps adding them and not clearing the one before.

Comment: Do you know how to use [Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)? Are you reloading the page each time or are you using [window.history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)?

Comment: no so when you scroll all I need to do is toggle from /#studios to /#resident-memberships. I thought window.history.pushState would be overkill